# checking for decimal points using a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I wrote some code to check if two input variables contained decimal points as so:

```
while "." in n:
    print()
    print("Please enter only integer numbers")
    n = input("Please enter the numerator:")
    d = input("Please enter the denominator:")

while "." in d:
    print()
    print("Please enter only integer numbers")
    n = input("Please enter the numerator:")
    d = input("Please enter the denominator:")
```

however, I need a way for these loops to be ignored if the decimal is followed by a 0, e.g. 4.0 or 8.0.

Is there a way to do this, or is there a better way to check if the number entered is a decimal? I don't want to make the input a float from the beginning as it also needs to work if the user enters an integer.

The version of python I'm using is 3.5.4.

Comment: `while "." in n and ".0" not in n:` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this the solution you are looking for

```
while int(float(d)) != float(d) or int(float(n)) != float(n):
```

other answers won't work for numbers like `8.05`

Comment: you're right, however, I can't seem to get this to work, keep getting this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.4'. any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it is because you can't give a "float string" as input to the int function.
I edited the code and it should work now @YasminPaksoy

Answer (score 1):

To piggy-back off of @public static void main 's answer,
you can also consolidate your loop.

```
while ("." in n and ".0" not in n) or ("." in d and ".0" not in d):
    n = input("Enter the numerator: ")
    d = input("Enter the denominator: ")
```

Comment: what about `"8.005"`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
while "." in n:
```

with this:

```
while "." in n and ".0" not in n:
```

This makes the code in the loop execute when "." is found in `n`, but ".0" is *not* found in `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider comparing them as the actual value types:

`while int(float(d)) != float(d) or int(float(n)) != float(n):`

Comment: you should try to provide a more constructive and orginal answer, this one looks very similar to one that is already been posted

Comment: That is true, however at the time of writing the code in the other answer was broken and I was unable to leave a comment about it there.

Comment: Editing an answer is seen as contribution too

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! Did not know I could edit an answer when I wasn't even allowed to comment...

Comment: you can always *suggest* edits, meaning that other users will have to review them before they take effect. you do need 2k reputation to make edits without them being reviewed.